# Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1?

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

i  deploying functions
Running command:

```
npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .
```

```
C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\emart\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\functions\\products\\delivery.js
22:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
28:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
34:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
40:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
50:39  error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='            eqeqeq
58:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
116:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
118:5   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return

C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\emart\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\functions\\products\\parcel_delivery.js
22:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
27:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
36:39  error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='            eqeqeq
44:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
102:9   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return
104:5   warning  Async arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return

C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\emart\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\functions\\products\\schedule_ride.js
13:35  error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
26:31  warning  Unexpected function expression       prefer-arrow-callback
37:17  warning  Function expected no return value    consistent-return
46:13  warning  Function expected no return value    consistent-return
63:48  error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq
63:77  error    Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq

C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\emart\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\Order Tracking Firebase Function\\functions\\triggers.js
30:5  warning  Arrow function expected no return value  consistent-return

✖ 21 problems (5 errors, 16 warnings)
0 errors and 1 warning potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\\Users\\pazto\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v16.20.2\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\cross-env\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (C:\\Users\\pazto\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v16.20.2\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\cross-env\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:40:16)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\\Users\\pazto\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v16.20.2\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\cross-env\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:27:25)
at Process.ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\\Users\\pazto\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v16.20.2\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\cross-env\\node_modules\\cross-spawn\\lib\\enoent.js:30:37)
at Process.ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12) {
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
spawnargs: \[\]
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1
```

[image]